# Analyzing automatic current switch

Tags: current-measurement, comparator

I'm trying to learn more about automatic current range switch and stumbled across [Nordic's nRF6707 power profiler kit](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Kits/Power-Profiler-Kit) that has very interesting topology to choose between three different current ranges.

Now I "understand how" this circuit works but what I'm having hard time with is figuring out how to start analyzing thresholds, different initial conditions and in general doing analysis of this circuit in order to modify it.

Here is the screenshot of the schematic portion for automatic switch:

[image: nRF6707 power profiler automatic switch]

What I'm having trouble with and could really use help with, is suggestions on how to start analyzing automatic switch portion. I'm not sure how to find steady-state values and also initial conditions (although I assume both SW1 and SW2 should be off on power-up with no load) and also how to analyze transitions when measured current crosses Vref On/Off thresholds (in up or down direction).

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: " in order to modify it." - what do you want to modify about it?

Comment: In general, I would like to understand how the circuit works.
I'm not planning on using same components (different op-amps) and also sense resistor values will be different and etc.